# Get the absolute path of a file to be uploaded

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, absolute-path

I am uploading a file using a simple FileUpload control named `theFile` (ASP.NET). I'm trying to get the absolute path of the file, but `thefile.PostedFile.FileName` and `thefile.FileName` are the exact same, just the file name, no path! I can't use Server.MapPath because I will be saving this file on a different server (transferring via byte array through a webservice).

It breaks at this line:

```
Dim fStream As New FileStream(thefile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

because it is taking the filename and mapping it to the relative path of my VS! I need the absolute path...

Comment: Which version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: basically, i want to know what the path of the file is that the person is trying to upload, so i can take it and create a filestream out of it

Comment: HTML form having enctype=multipart/form-data and post method is responsible to upload the file content (not a file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A file uploaded through HTTP will never contain the full path on the remote (client) machine  - it could give away information about their directory structure, and so is considered a security risk.  Plus, what use would it be? If someone is uploading you a file from over the internet, why would you be trying to open a filestream on your local (asp.net server) machine to the path that existed on their machine?

Uploaded files actually come through as a stream of bytes as part of the request.  You need to access the [FileBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) property of the control to get the file, or call the SaveAs() method to save it to the server.  In your case, you could probably just get the bytes and send them off to the webservice call you need to make.

Comment: how do i create a filestream without knowing the path of the file i'm trying to get?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused.  The uploaded file exists as a stream of bytes as part of the HTTP request. There is no relation between this stream of bytes and a file on the file system, until you save it to disk.

Comment: @Jason: As Hadi said, use the FileContent property to use the underlying stream of the uploaded file.

Comment: Yep... it's all covered in the links that we posted... looks like we both linked the same page.

Answer (score 1):

> (transferring via byte array through a webservice).

Since you're currently requiring the File Byte Array, why not access the file's Byte Array through theFile.FileBytes property ?

Here is the reference to the FileBytes property of the FileUpload web control : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx

If you would like to access the Stream object directly, you can utilize the FileContent property. Here is the reference to the FileContent property of the FileUpload web control : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx