# Get file upload data from post data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I am looping through the posted values on a form with a view to doing something with them (so don't have access to the controls themselves). This is the process I have to take on this project so that is why I'm doing it this way.

On the form I will have a file upload box but I am not sure how I would upload the file that has been selected from it as I can't just do `Control.SaveAs()`. When I return the posted value using `Request.Form.Item[i]` I get the file name I chose but not the full path like I would expect.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297939/get-the-absolute-path-of-a-file-to-be-uploaded/1297977#1297977

Comment: @Womp - The problem is that method seems to be using the control to directly get the data. I am looping through the posted data using `Request.Form.Count` and `Request.Form.Item[i]` so don't have access to the control directly. It is done this way as this is a user generated form and they can enter any form controls they like.

Comment: Right, I understand.  There is no way that I know of to obtain the full path of the file though.  Are you looking to get the bytes of the actual file itself?  I can post how to do that....

Comment: I see what your problem is now.  You're looping through the Form post data, not the Controls collection.  You will need to check the Request.Files[] collection for your file content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the uploaded files directly, and not through a FileUploader control, you should use the `Request.Files` collection and not the `Request.Form`

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. KInda obvious now you mention it though *blush*

Answer (score 0):

File Upload controls only pass the file name and the contents.  I'm not sure why you would need a folder name, especially since the folder name would be for the client - I can't expect that this would have any value to you since you want to save the file on the server.

As I am unsure of your goals, I would recommend using `Server.MapPath("~/Folder")` to find a suitable folder to save your uploaded files to

Comment: I don't need to find a folder to save the folder to, I just don't know what to do with the file name I retrieve from the posted value. If was to do this in PHP I could get the posted image value and have a full client path from which I could write a script to upload the file. I seem to only have access to the file name this way which doesn't help much.

Comment: Are you trying to roll your own upload control over a non-HTTP protocol (such as FTP)?  You can't use a FileUpload control for that, as it simply renders an <input type='file'> html tag.